# Is there any way to load MIDI into AKAppleSequencer or AKSequencer without using a file?

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

I want to use **AudioKit** to play MIDI but all the docs point to loading MIDI files from a path/URL. Is there any way to use a string for this?

I am currently using AKAppleSequencer (https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKAppleSequencer.html) but I couldn't find how to initialize it with the contents of a MIDI file without having the file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that depends on the string. If you have a full midi file in a string, you could save it temporarily to load it up. Alternatively, you could take AKMIDIFile and use it as a base for AKMIDIString and where it converts the file data, you could use the string data.

Comment: As I'm using `AKAppleSequencer` with AudioKit 4.9.1 it looks like there's no `AKMIDIFile` usage. There's an internal use of `MusicSequenceFileLoad` but I can't override that function because it uses internal members.